# Which books/papers are good source for the concept of dual numbers over a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hypercomplex-numbers

Recently I came across the concept of dual numbers over a ring, $R[\epsilon] = \{a+b\epsilon ~|~ a,b \in R ~\text{and}~ \epsilon^2 = 0 \}$. I want to learn more about these rings. Hence looking for a nice source. Please suggest me some books/papers.

Comment: You could start by looking at questions/answers on [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ring+of+dual+numbers)

Comment: What do you want to learn precisely? I find your question extremely broad, they are rings that come up in various contexts, but you won't find a systematic study of them. I you have specific questions about certain properties of those rings you should ask them directly.

Comment: @Captain Lama, I want to know about its algebraic structure and derive some number-theoretic properties like that of Gaussian integers.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find what you are looking for. For a general ring $R$ this is way too broad (you can't say anything about $R[\epsilon]$ without making hypotheses about $R$), and for specific $R$ (like if $R$ is a field for instance) it's too easy so it won't be spelled out in a book.

Comment: @Captain Lama, Ok I want to know about $\mathbb{Z}[\epsilon]$ that is the ring of dual numbers over integers. If you have any source in mind, please tell me.